# Java 8 ForkJoin Unexplained Output

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, java-8, fork-join

I was playing with the `ForkJoin` framework and Java 8 `accumulateAndGet`function. The following program produced an output that I couldn't explain. Can you?

*P.S: This is not a homework. This is an exercise from the book "Java SE 8 for the Really Impatient" by Cay S. Horstmann. It's a good book.*

```
/**
* Q1: Write a program that keeps track of the longest string that is observed by a number of threads. Use an
* {@code AtomicReference} and an appropriate accumulator.
* 
* @param observed
*            Longest string.
* @param x
*            String value to be compared to the longest value.
* @return Longest string.
*/
public static String updateLongestString(final AtomicReference<String> observed, final String x) {
    LOGGER.info("Received observed: {}, x: {}", observed, x);

    final String longestString = observed.accumulateAndGet(x,
        maxBy((str1, str2) -> observed.get().length() - x.length()));

    LOGGER.info("New observed: {}.", longestString);

    return longestString;
}
```

Unit test:

```
@Test
public void testUpdateLongestString() {
    final String[] words = new String[] { "Java 8", "Java 8 is Awesome!",
                "Java 8 is the Best thing Since Sliced Bread!", "Java 8 Changes Everything!" };
    final int len = words.length;
    final int stopAfter = 100;

    final AtomicReference<String> longestString = new AtomicReference<>(words[0]);
    final AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger(1);

    class UpdateLongestStringTask extends RecursiveAction {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -2288401002001447054L;

        private int id = -1;

        private UpdateLongestStringTask(final int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        @Override
        protected void compute() {
            LOGGER.info("Executing task #: {}.", id);

            if (count.get() >= stopAfter) {
                return;
            }

            final ForkJoinTask<Void> task = new UpdateLongestStringTask(count.incrementAndGet()).fork();

            updateLongestString(longestString, words[randomIndex()]);

            task.join();
        }

        private int randomIndex() {             
            return ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(len);
        }
    }

    /* Just because we can. */
    final int parallelism = min(getRuntime().availableProcessors(), 4);

    new ForkJoinPool(parallelism).invoke(new UpdateLongestStringTask(count.get()));
}
```

Output (line marked -->> can't be explained; how come it's printing a value it never apparently received):

```
2015-01-05 23:20:00.974 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1] [INFO ] n.a.j.j.c.PracticeQuestionsCh6Test - Executing task #: 1.
2015-01-05 23:20:00.980 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-2] [INFO ] n.a.j.j.c.PracticeQuestionsCh6Test - Executing task #: 2.
2015-01-05 23:20:00.980 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-3] [INFO ] n.a.j.j.c.PracticeQuestionsCh6Test - Executing task #: 3.
2015-01-05 23:20:00.980 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-0] [INFO ] n.a.j.j.c.PracticeQuestionsCh6Test - Executing task #: 4.
2015-01-05 23:20:00.981 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-0] [INFO ] n.a.j.j.c.PracticeQuestionsCh6 - Received observed: Java 8, x: Java 8 Changes Everything!
2015-01-05 23:20:00.980 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-3] [INFO ] n.a.j.j.c.PracticeQuestionsCh6 - Received observed: Java 8, x: Java 8
2015-01-05 23:20:00.980 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1] [INFO ] n.a.j.j.c.PracticeQuestionsCh6 - Received observed: Java 8, x: Java 8 is Awesome!
2015-01-05 23:20:00.980 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-2] [INFO ] n.a.j.j.c.PracticeQuestionsCh6 - Received observed: Java 8, x: Java 8 is the Best thing Since Sliced Bread!
2015-01-05 23:20:01.028 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-0] [INFO ] n.a.j.j.c.PracticeQuestionsCh6 - New observed: Java 8 Changes Everything!.

-->> 2015-01-05 23:20:01.028 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-3] [INFO ] n.a.j.j.c.PracticeQuestionsCh6 - New observed: Java 8 Changes Everything!.

2015-01-05 23:20:01.028 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1] [INFO ] n.a.j.j.c.PracticeQuestionsCh6 - New observed: Java 8 is Awesome!.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you provide a function, that function should operate on its arguments, i.e.

```
final String longestString = observed.accumulateAndGet(x,
    maxBy((str1, str2) -> observed.get().length() - x.length()));
```

is heavily violating the contract of the functional API. `accumulateAndGet` will provide an atomic update regarding the specified operation but not regarding another `get` operation within the function.

It’s not clear why you did this as implementing the correct function is straight-forward:

```
final String longestString = observed.accumulateAndGet(x,
    maxBy((str1, str2) -> str1.length() - str2.length()));
```

or

```
final String longestString =
    observed.accumulateAndGet(x, maxBy(comparingInt(String::length)));
```

---

Note that after fixing the code you still might observe a result different than the two values you have logged before as `accumulateAndGet` provides you an atomic update but this atomicity does not expand to logging operations you performed *before* invoking `accumulateAndGet`. The logged content of the `AtomicReference` might be outdated at the time when the atomic update is performed. But due to the contract of the update and your provided operator that resulting `String` will have at least the same size as the maximum of your previously seen values.

Further, keep in mind that the perceived order of log operations doesn’t say anything about the actual order of performed update operations.

You may get a better view of what happens when changing the code as follows:

```
public static String updateLongestString(AtomicReference<String> observed, String x) {

    final String longestString = observed.accumulateAndGet(x, maxBy((str1, str2) -> {
        LOGGER.info("Received str1: {}, str2: {}", str1, str2);
        return str1.length() - str2.length();
    }));

    LOGGER.info("New observed: {}.", longestString);

    return longestString;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. There're a couple of things I'd like to say (sorry if the formatting doesn't come out right):  
*"If you provide a function, that function should operate on its arguments" - in general this isn't true as lambdas can operate anything that's effectively final.  
* The Javadoc for `accumulateAndGet` says "The function is applied with the current value as its first argument, and the given update as the second argument.". That's the reason I used the `get`. But thinking about it now, there's no safeguard on the `get` call.

Comment: You are mixing up what lambdas can do and what the contract of the API implies. The documentation of [`accumulateAndGet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.html#accumulateAndGet-V-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) clearly says: “*The function should be side-effect-free, since it may be re-applied when attempted updates fail due to contention among threads.*” The API does not mandate that you implement the `BinaryOperator` using a lambda, and in fact, you didn’t. So in principle you can do even more than lambda expressions allow but…

Comment: You're right about the API but how's `get` causing any side effects? It's not incrementing/decrementing the counter. BTW, I accepted your answer as it's the only one and clearly written.

Comment: In this special case the effects are rather limited. Due to possible concurrent updates your additional `get` call might receive a value which differs from the first argument but in this case the follow-up `cas` operation will fail anyway. So the worst thing which can happen is that there are more retries needed than necessary (you are effectively performing more reads with `volatile` semantics thus slowing the atomic update down). But in general you are better off implementing functions as real functions, i.e. which depend on arguments and constants but not on concurrently mutable values.

Comment: Btw. my example violates the contract as well as logging is a side-effect but it’s only intended to help understanding what happens and should not appear in production code in this form.